# Open multiselect with another button (primeng, angular)

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

Is there a way to open a primeng [multiselect](https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect) using another button?

I've tried triggering by clicking on the nativeElement, but that has not worked.

Below is my component:

```
<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" #filterButton (click)="openMultiselect()">Trigger remotely</button>
</div>

<div class="ui-g">
  <div class="ui-g-6 ui-fluid">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="cities1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities1"></p-multiSelect>
  </div>
</div>
```

And TS:

```
@ViewChild(MultiSelect) filterButton: MultiSelect;

  openMultiselect() {
    this.filterButton.el.nativeElement.click()
  }
```

And stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngprime-multiselect-azdsh4

Comment: You should be assigning the template reference to the multiselect instead of the button as the button isn't a multiselect element. Doing that, you should be able to call ```multiselect.show()```

Comment: @nullptr.t Thanks.  Updated with that in stackblitz, but wasn't able to get that to work.  Does it work for you?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngprime-multiselect-azdsh4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two steps you need to do to achieve it:

- call public `MultiSelect::show` method
- stop propagation of event in order to prevent closing dialog during the same action

**html**

```
<button (click)="openMultiselect($event)" ...
```

**ts**

```
@ViewChild(MultiSelect) multiSelect: MultiSelect;

openMultiselect(e) {
  this.multiSelect.show();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngprime-multiselect-1k2sjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 2):

```js
Typescript
@ViewChild('refMulSel') refMulSel: MultiSelect

 toggleMulSel: boolean = false;
  openMulSel(e) {
    this.toggleMulSel = !this.toggleMulSel;
    if (this.toggleMulSel) {
      this.refMulSel.show();
    } else {
      this.refMulSel.hide();
    }`enter code here`

    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

```html
Html
<span (click)="openMulSel($event)" >Open</span>
<p-multiSelect  #refMulSel></p-multiSelect>
```